# Grey out an image in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this from another question and it works perfectly in Chrome and FF,  but not in IE (i currently have ie 11.0.9)

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
-o-filter: grayscale(0%);
filter: grayscale(0%);
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
                        -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
```

Is there any way to make an image grey in ie with css or js?

Comment: Have you tried the -ms- prefix?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about pre IE10(IE6-9), you need to add: 
`filter: gray;`